# How do I make jQuery work correctly in an ES6 file

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ecmascript-6, laravel-5.8

I can't yet figure out why jquery is not working inside my class, does somebody have an idea?

I use jQuery 3.4.0, Laravel-mix 'app.js' (does load jQuery correctly if jQuery is called inside `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {});`) and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

```js
var NavbarComponents = function() {
  var _componentSelect2 = function() {
    if (!$().select2) {
      console.log('Warning - select2.min.js is not loaded.');
      return;
    }
  }

return {
  init: function() {
    _componentSelect2();
  }
}
}();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  NavbarComponents.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

For example this `$` function doesn't work, I get a 'function is undefined error'.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Laravel mix file -->
  <!-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}" defer></script> -->

  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script src="{{ asset('plugins/jquery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src"{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

  <!-- Theme file -->
  <script src="{{ asset('plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>

  <!-- The custom js script -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/admin/navbar_components.js')}}"></script>
</head>
```

Also loading the latest jQuery version from a CDN doesn't work.

This works apperantly

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ntm8r0u/1/)

Comment: And right-click view-source to see if the script tags are correct

Comment: If your code is in the `app.js` file then you need to put that reference *after* `jquery-3.4.0.min.js`

Comment: How about replace the $ to jQuery?

Comment: the app.js file is a laravel core file that loads axios, jquery and other stuff

Comment: @Pinetree This doesn't work. A funny fact tho, jquery works in my other project which uses laravel with react.

Comment: Change your code `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {});` to `jQuery(document).ready(function () { var $ = jQuery; ...your code aflter it });` and have a try.

Comment: Have you checked the generated source? Everything loads in the correct order? Does every generated referenced js file link to an existing file? Start there.

Comment: Yeah i'm already trying different stuff for a few hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded datatables with jquery in my file dumb mistake because now i was using jquery twice.

Sorry and thanks for your time!

Comment: Please accept your own answer so we can see the question is solved already.